# jQuery automatically click key word buttons

Tags: jquery, key

Is it possible automatically click TAB and than Enter buttons on page load using jQuery ?
I have tried to find but there is nothing about key auto click.

Comment: Why don't you just try to do whatever it is that clicking Tab and then Enter will do?

Comment: i have button in iframe so cant get element inside it but if onload jquery will repeat same way as i type on my keyboard Tab than Enter the button inside iframe will be clicked ...

Comment: Is the iframe to a different domain? If so you can't do anything in there. If not I can post some kind of answer if you posted your markup.